# How to integrate a wordpress site with Joomla 3.0

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, joomla, joomla3.0

I have an established wordpress with a members section and forum, the whole site is being redeveloped but with Joomla 3.0, A lot of the content  will have to be just copied and pasted into the new site  but the owner of the site wants to keep the old wordpress site up for a while and possible blend it into the newer joomla site with css and styling.

I've tried throwing one site on top of the other and the only two files that collide are the license.txt (that I won't worry about)and the index.php file.

Both sites will work fine if its their index.php but if it's wordpress's index.php the links on joomla will give an error, and if it's Joomla's index.php, any wordpress links will go to the joomla index page.

What is the best way to engineer this to the main index.php will be Joomla ?

Here is the wordpress index.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Front to the WordPress application. This file doesn't do anything, but loads
 * wp-blog-header.php which does and tells WordPress to load the theme.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

/**
 * Tells WordPress to load the WordPress theme and output it.
 *
 * @var bool
 */
define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);


/** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
require('./wp-blog-header.php')
```

Thanks

Comment: You could install WordPress in a `blog/` directory?

Comment: Putting two websites in one directory is worst idea ever! Just put wordpress in separated dir as @andrewsi said and use .htaccess to rewrite urls if you want to.

Comment: I would prefer to use just one directory but the owner is afraid of  loosing google rankings from the links. Just looking for a work around.

Answer (score 1):

1st thing I want to mention here is having two separate cmss' in a directory is a bad idea. If had searched a bit on google you would find this helpful.

[JConverter](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/migration-a-conversion/data-import-a-export/10237)

> As the name suggests, JConverter allows you to convert your WordPress
> blog into a Joomla site. It can import users, blog posts, categories,
> pages and even links from your WordPress blog to Joomla.

If you are not sure about the quality you can start reading the comments.

## Advice

have a separate folder for two cmss and use a .htacess file to get the job done. You can find tons of articles explaining how it should be done.

Comment: Also, take a note of the limitations of this extension. They may put you off it completely is it's a major issue

Answer (score 0):

After thinking about it here are the options I think I have

Option 1)
Both Wordpress and and Joomla can coexist on the same root folder, the only files where there is a conflict would be the index.php (and some license text file) and this could be engineered in such a way to work, but having 2 content management systems on the same domain root isn't a great idea in the long term as the root domain has loads of files there and updates and security patches in the future, it's open to something going wrong.

Option 2)
Put the new Joomla site on the root and then move the older site into another folder then use apache rewrite and an .htaccess file that would rewrite the location of the word press files and thus keep the original links

Option 3)
There is a component of Joomla called wordpress for Joomla which makes Wordpress a part of Joomla and would keep all the links of the original, But it's designed for people who have a Joomla site and want a dedicated blogging tool like Wordpress, not the other way round. I was talking to the developers and there unsure if this would work the other way round and then there's plugins ect to think about.

Option 4)
Leave the the current wordpress site in the same position and upload the new site to a new folder called /en/ (As in an english version)

Option 5)
JConverter still only in beta

I'm going with option 4:)

Comment: What is the point of having a new site made if the root folder still points to the old one?

Answer (score 0):

Why would you keep both sites? That just means duplicate content and is going to stop the new version of the site from ranking. The best option in my opinion is ditching your old site and making sure the URL either are the same (which can be achieved with a SEF component such as sh404sef) or use 301 redirects to your new URLs which will tell Google the URL has permanently changed.